# ipad - keyboard inside popover?

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to have the keyboard show inside a UIPopOver instead of filling the screen width?

something like the image...

[image]

Comment: So, you want to make the keyboard more difficult to use?

Comment: @Marcelo: I think he specifically is in need of more screen width than ease of keypad usage. Further, I don't know how would this style make keyboard more difficult to use? I guess it should be more easy to use - just a personal opinion.

Comment: exactly. I need to adjust the text property of an object. If the popover has 320x480 and the keyboard is inside, it will be the same size of iphone's keyboard (that is not difficult to type). It is just more clever to type the text inside the popover as I am changing the object's text, instead of having the popover there and the huge keyboard outside...

Comment: @Harpreet: I understand what @DR wants. I'm trying to point out that it's a bad idea, and that the app's design should work around the keyboard as-is. A keyboard like the one shown above would be awful to use. It would be small like the iPhone keyboard, but with the thumbs much further apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. You'd have to implement your own keyboard to do this.